# iFrame loading pdf blank

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe, blob

After spending a good amount of time in searching I finally decide to raise another similar question here.

**Objective**
I want to display PDF to an iFrame.

**Issue**
iFrame is loading the pdf and rendering the pages but the content is completely blank.

**What I am doing -**
I am getting a response as a binary pdf file from the backend, I am creating Blob and then objectUrl of that blob and setting the URL to the src of iFrame.

My code is working and showing a sample Pdf in the iFrame. But not working for other PDFs.

**My code -**

```
 $.ajax(settings).done(function(response){
   console.log("my response ==>", response)
   const blob = new Blob([response], {type:'application/pdf'})
   const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob) // creating the url with help of URL API
   let PdfURL = document.getElementById('iframePdfURL') 
   PdfURL.src=url // here setting the src of iframe of id =>(iframePdfURL)
   URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
}).fail(function(error){
   console.log(error);
})
```

**Cases I**
*The following code is working fine when I am getting a response of PDF version - %PDF-1.3*

[image]

[image]

**Case II**
*The above code is not working and showing a blank pdf when I am getting the response of PDF version - %PDF-1.4*

[image]

[image]

I am not sure about **%PDF-1.4** is that really a version or something else but as much I have noticed pdf that has this in the response is not working.
What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: @KJ Thank you for letting me know I was unaware of what 1.3 and 1.4 was.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is facing the issue, here is how I have resolved it.

On the above code, I was creating a Blob of pdf binary manually, I am not sure what was causing the issue that for one pdf it was working and for another, it was not working but now I changed my code and instead of creating blob manually I am using `$http` (I am using AngularJS) to get blob by using  `responseType: "blob"`.

Code -

```
    $http({
      url: settings.url,
      method: "GET",
      responseType: "blob",
      headers:{
       "Authorization": "Bearer <?php echo $jwt; ?>"
      }
     }).then(function(response) {
      var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(response.data);
      $('#iframePdfURL').attr('src',fileURL);
   });
```

As I am using AngularJS I used $http but I found we can also do the same and request blob as responseType with `fetch` API.

I hope this will help.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

DataURL has file size (length) limitation
Chrome - 2mb